# Building an executable with PyInstaller on Windows

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller, mozilla-deepspeech

I want to create a Windows executable using [PyInstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

My project has the following dependencies:

- [deepspeech](https://deepspeech.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)
- [PyAudio](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/) (which in turn depends on the [PortAudio](http://portaudio.com/) C library)
- [tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html)

I tried building the executable by running the command below:

```
pyinstaller entrypoint.py --name speech-to-text-gui --onedir --hidden-import numpy.random.common --hidden-import numpy.random.bounded_integers --hidden-import numpy.random.entropy
```

I initially tried building without any `--hidden-import` arguments, but then I would get errors like

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.random.common'
```

After the build, when I run the executable, it crashes with the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "entrypoint.py", line 1, in 
    from speech_to_text_gui.__main__ import main
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "speech_to_text_gui\__main__.py", line 5, in 
    from speech_to_text_gui import speech_to_text_gui
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "speech_to_text_gui\speech_to_text_gui.py", line 16, in 
    from deepspeech import Model
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "deepspeech\__init__.py", line 23, in 
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "deepspeech\impl.py", line 13, in 
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
[12236] Failed to execute script 'entrypoint' due to unhandled exception!
```

The program runs fine when I run it directly with `python entrypoint.py`.

I looked through the [PyInstaller "If Things Go Wrong" page](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/If-Things-Go-Wrong) but nothing jumped out at me as wrong with how I am building.

I also tried building on Linux, and the executable built and ran just fine without any runtime errors on Linux.

From the traceback, my guess is loading a DLL for deepspeech failed, since that is the last call in the traceback. But take that with a grain of salt.

I am looking for any suggestions anyone might have to troubleshoot this build.

Comment: try `--collect-binaries deepspeech`

Comment: @gfdsweds That worked! If you turn your comment into an answer, I can accept it.